# jQuery How to add class to <li> or <a> and keep it on the next page load or refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have `<li>` elements, containing `<a>` elements. When the user clicks on the `<a>`, it sets class 'active' to the `<a>` and loads the new link. But when the new link is loaded, the class 'active' disappears. How to make that when the new page comes up still to have 'active' class on the same `<a>`?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use something that is persisted between pages, such as cookies or localstorage. On page load, you would have to inspect persisted data to see what changes need to be made to the page to bring it back to where it was previously.

Comment: You can use cookies or localstorage.

Comment: ...or even GET attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to persist the state between page changes. You could do that in one of two ways:

1. Session parameter: Use cookies or local storage (HTML5)
2. Request parameter: Add a URL parameter and read it via jquery (example: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way is to keep it in a cookie. Here's the example code how to create/read cookie: **[LINK](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script)**

In your case you'd need to add an ID or some unique attribute for each `<a>` or `<li>` so when the page reloads, the script knows which `<a>` should be activated, e.g.:

**HTML**:

```
<li><a href="abc.html" data-unique-attr="123">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="def.html" data-unique-attr="456">link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="ghi.html" data-unique-attr="789">link 3</a></li>
```

**jQuery**:

```
// on page load: read the cookie and activate the link
$(function() {
    var activeAnchor = readCookie('activeAnchor');
    if (activeAnchor) {
        $('li a[data-unique-attr="' + activeAnchor + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
});

// on click: set the cookie
$('li a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    createCookie('activeAnchor', $(this).data('uniqueAttr'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the link in question matches the page's url, you can base your code on that instead of a cookie or something.

```
$(function() { //The document is ready...
    $('li a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Note that in this form, it only works if the link is absolute, i.e. starting with `http://`. If the link is relative you may want to adapt this a little bit.